# Regex help, works on rubular not on production? Possible \n issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Given this:

```
Come Find me please. This is paragraph one.\n\nThis is paragraph two. 
Capture everything before me as this is the last sentence.\n\n\n\n
From: XXX XXX <xxxxx@gmail.com>\nDate: Mon, 17 May 2010 10:59:40 -0700\n
To: \"xxx, xxx\" <xxxxx@intuit.com>\nSubject: Re: XXXXXXXX\n\ndone

Lots of other junk here
```

What I want back is:

```
Come Find me please. This is paragraph one.\n\nThis is paragraph two. 
Capture everything before me as this is the last sentence.
```

I'm using the following regex which works fine on rubular but fails in rails. Ideas why?

```
split(/(From:.*Date.*To:.*Subject:.*?)\n/m).first
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as far as I tested, except that it is trailed with some `"\n"`. If you want to remove them, add `\n*` to the beginning. I am not sure why you have the parentheses, and the last `?` and `\n`. I took them off.

```
your_string.split(/\n*From:.*Date.*To:.*Subject:.*/m).first
```

Maybe using `sub` is more natural.

```
your_string.sub(/\n*From:.*Date.*To:.*Subject:.*/m, '')
```

You can also do this:

```
 your_string[/.*?(?=\n*From:.*Date.*To:.*Subject:.*)/m]
```

Comment: Hi tried the first suggestion. But that is returning the FROM DATE TO SUBJECT Block

Comment: Can you tell me what is returned if you remove the `first` from the code? Are you using the same string that you posted here, surrounded with double quotation? I checked my code, and it worked fine. I suspect the string that you tested might be somewhat different. If it is different, please post here. And does it mean that my other codes worked?

Comment: Are you sure that you have `"\n"`, not `"\r"` or both in your string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution if want to extract every thing before `From:`

```
txt.gsub(/From:.*$/m, '')
```

The `/m` option makes the `.` match newlines.

Comment: Thanks but I need more than just from to prevent false positives which is why I have those other fields.

Answer (score 0):

If the word "From: "  is unique,

```
>> s
=> "Come Find me please. This is paragraph one.\n\nThis is paragraph two. \nCapture everything before me as this is the last sentence.\n\n\n\n\nFrom: XXX XXX <xxxxx@gmail.com>\nDate: Mon, 17 May 2010 10:59:40 -0700\n\nTo: \"xxx, xxx\" <xxxxx@intuit.com>\nSubject: Re: XXXXXXXX\n\ndone"

>> s.split(/From:\s+/).first.strip
=> "Come Find me please. This is paragraph one.\n\nThis is paragraph two. \nCapture everything before me as this is the last sentence."
```